# Closest Approach question for math/physics heads

Tags: math, physics

I'm using a Segment to Segment closest approach method which will output the closest distance between two segments of length.   Each segment corresponds to a sphere object's origin and destination.  The speed is simply from one point, to the other.

Closest Approach can succeed even when there won't be a real collision. So, I'm currently using a 10-step method and calculating the distance between 2 spheres as they move along the two segments.  So, basically the length of each segment is the object's traverse in the physics step, and the radius is the objects radius.  By stepping, I can tell where they collide, and if they collide (Sort of; for the MOST part.)..

I get the feeling that there could be something better.  While I sort of believe that the first closest approach call is required, I think that the method immediately following it is a TAD weak.  Can anyone help me out?  I can illustrate this if needed.

Thanks alot!
[image]
<sub>(source: [yfrog.com](http://img444.yfrog.com/img444/6692/caquestion.png))</sub>

Comment: But it's not a __programming__ question... >_o

Comment: Closest Approach is an algorithm.  It very much is my friend.

Comment: It could be... if he's working on a physics engine.

Comment: @rlb.usa: I think it probably is; it seems to be about collision detection... it's just not completely clear exactly what the question is.

Comment: @Kyle: I think the key thing we're missing here is some notion of the input you have. You say "variable speed" - is the variable speed a known function, so that you could use an approximation method to find closest approach (or maybe even collision directly)? Or is it something unknown, so that you really do have to step through?

Comment: 2 Spheres step in a certain distance and direction per iteration.  I just need to know at which point they collide.  Think of it like, say, the pool games that sort of preview a ghost render of your cue ball hitting another ball on the table, however both balls would be moving in this case.

Comment: I'm just looking for a non-sub-stepping method.  I want an exact point  of collision given that each of the two spheres start a certain spot, and end up at a certain spot per iteration.

Comment: @Kyle: So you're already stepping in time? Is the resolution of that step small enough that you can simply check for a collision each step? Or do you need to know where within the step it happened? In that case, is there some reason you can't assume the velocity was constant through the step, and solve directly?

Comment: The Closest Approach algorithm will tell you how close two segments come together.  While that works quite well in a reality without time, it doesn't tell you, say, that the sphere is merely right behind the other sphere, tailing it at speed.  My sub-step method is to figure out if there actually is a collision.

Comment: @Kyle: It sounds like you're saying essentially that the closest approach algorithm doesn't actually give you the answer. I stand by what I've said: we need to know exactly what data you're starting from. Presumably you're testing for a collision within a given time step of your main program. Within that time step, are the velocities of the two spheres constant? Are they a known function?

Comment: @Kyle: The general approach you should be able to take is to write the distance between the two spheres as a function of time and solve for when it's equal to the sum of their radii (being careful to detect if there is no solution). The exact method depends on the parameters. If you have (approximately, at this time scale) constant velocities, you can solve directly. If you can calculate the position and velocity at any given time, you can use newton's method.

Comment: To recap: there are two spheres, each moving with constant velocity during a given time period. The initial and final positions are given, and also the radii of the spheres, and you want an exact formula for whether they collide, and if so where they are at the time. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, Beta.  That's right on.   I posted an illustration through an edit.

Comment: @Kyle: what's the project? Is this for a game, or just homework?

Comment: It's a game.  The objects are cars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I don't know how to post graphics; bear with me.)

All right, we have two spheres with radii r1 and r2, starting at locations X1 and X2, moving with velocities V1 and V2 (X's and V's are vectors).

The velocity of sphere 1 as seen from sphere 2 is

```
V = V1-V2
```

and its direction is

```
v = V/|V|
```

The distance sphere 1 must travel (in the frame of sphere 2) to closest approach is

```
s = Xv
```

And if X is the initial separation, then the distance of closest approach is

```
h = |X - Xv|
```

This is where graphics would help. If h > r1+r2, there will be no collision. Suppose h < r1+r2. At the time of collision, the two sphere centers and the point of closest approach will form a right triangle. The distance from Sphere 1's center to the point of closest approach is

```
u = sqrt((r1 + r2)^2 - h^2)
```

So the distance sphere 1 has traveled is

```
s - u
```

Now just see if sphere 1 travels that far in the given interval. If so, then you know exactly when and where the spheres were (you must shift back from sphere 2's frame, but that's pretty easy). If not, there's no collision.

Comment: Thanks, Beta!  I guess I'm not sure what the X represents in Xv, and what operation you're doing.  So, I guess I'm stuck on that particular part.

Comment: Sorry, X is the initial separation of the spheres (X2 - X1), v is a unit vector in the direction of V, and when I write two vectors together like Xv, I mean the dot product.

Answer (score 3):

Closest approach can be done without simulating time if the position function is invertible and explicit.

1. Pick a path and object.
2. Find the point on the path where the two paths are closest. If time has bounds (e.g. paths are line segments), ignore the bounds in this step.
3. Find the time at which the object is at the point from the previous step.
4. If time has bounds, limit the picked time by the bounds.
5. Calculate the position of the other object at the time from the previous step.
6. Check if the objects overlap.

This won't work for all paths (e.g. some cubic), but should work for linear paths.

Comment: In the case where two objects are moving in two segments which form a sort of 'V' shape, with them originating at the top of the V, their actual collision point wouldn't be the closest approach, it would actually be before it due to their radiuses.

Comment: So, due to that, I merely use the CA as a Boolean check to do the sub stepping.

Comment: @Kyle: for line segments rather than lines, you can find the closest point on one of them to the other.